# Wordpress: Adding "Tags" Section

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working with a clients website and their "tags" section was removed from the wordpress backend sidebar.  How do I re-add it? and How will they be able to add two worded tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Admin Menu Editor](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/12/20/admin-menu-editor-for-wordpress/) plugin is the easiest way to customize the Admin menu. Tags are located under the Posts item. You should be able to add them back this way.

Comment: with this plugin, Could I display the tags on the actual website like this:

Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag 4 and 5,etc.?